CakePHP 5 - Slugging for CakePHP
In the application I am working on, I use the 'Slug' plugin - https://github.com/UseMuffin/Slug I can fetch records in the default language without any problems, but I am unable to do so in the translated languages. A simplified PHP code looks like this:
public function index($slug=null)
{
    $this->ServiceUnits = $this->fetchTable('ServiceUnits');
    $serviceUnit = $this->ServiceUnits->find('slugged', slug: $slug)->first();
}


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `service_units` (
    `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `text` text,
    `slug` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `position` float DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `service_units_translations` (
    `id` int NOT NULL,
    `locale` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `text` text,
    `slug` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`locale`)
  );


How can I retrieve data from the service_units_translations table using the 'Slug' plugin?

The problem was solved in this way:
https://book.cakephp.org/5/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html#querying-translated-fields
